# How to handle HEAD request?

Tags: php, head

I have got request like this :

```
7327    xxxxxxx [26/Jul/2015:21:50:10 +0200]    -   200 www.xxx.xx"HEAD /dokonceniPlatby.php?merchantId=374&accountId=402&value=50.00&currency=CZK&methodId=1&description=N%C3%A1kup+zbo%C5%BE%C3%AD+v+na%C5%A1em+e-shopu&merchantData=2067&status=2&paymentId=91882&ipRating=&isOffline=0&needConfirm=1&isConfirm=1&signature=xxxxx HTTP/1.1"
```

How can i get these values like merchantId, or accountId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have this data ? try :

```
echo $_GET['merchantId'];  // or
echo $_REQUEST['merchantId'];
```

Otherwise you can get it with [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-str.php) :

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Answer (score 9):

**HEAD** request can be handled as if it was a **GET** request. You can access all parameters the same way - via **$_GET** or **$_REQUEST** superglobals.

The main difference is that your script **should not** return any content, if you want to adhere to **HTTP** specification. So process the request, return any headers that would be returned if it was a **GET** request, but **do not** return any content.